# Why does Spring Data's Sort.descending() reset ignoreCase?

Tags: spring-data

[Sort.descending()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html#descending--) javadoc states

"Returns a new Sort with the current setup but descending order direction."

Why does this test fail on the second assert? I would assume (and would like) `Sort.descending()` to keep `ignoreCase` as it is (true), but in practice it changes `ignoreCase` to false?

```
    @Test
    public void descendingSortShouldRetainCaseInsensitive() {
        var sort = Sort.by(Sort.Order.by("memberName").ignoreCase());
        assertTrue(sort.iterator().next().isIgnoreCase()); // 1 OK
        var sortDesc = sort.descending();
        assertTrue(sortDesc.iterator().next().isIgnoreCase()); // 2 fails
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was a bug, and has now been fixed: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2585